# Does bash keep the python instance open untill the script is done?

Tags: bash, windows-task-scheduler

I have a bash-script

```sh
python task1.py && python task2.py
```

they are both pretty memory heavy and it seems liek the memory hangs after `task1.py` is done i.e it keeps rising.
It is scheduled to run via. windows task manager if that has any influence.

Does windows create two python instances (one after the other is finished) and closes them when the script is done, or is it more like "open-close-open-close" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bash concatenation, launch the second command after the first one return, so the logic is **"open-close open-close"**.

When you `task.py` ends the python interpreter is closed and then reopened to execute the `task2.py`.

Comment: I just wonder how  I can run them after each-other w/o any memory issue but chaining them in the script throws and OOM error

Comment: Have you try to call it separately? Probably you will have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Your script doesn't affect the way the instances of Python are created internally.

These commands are run one after another, also only when `python task1.py` exits without errors.

Comment: But are the first python instance open untill the entire script is done?

Comment: No. Once your command is declared completed by the system, no in-memory resource related to it persists. There are exceptions, although it's purely specific to how your python script works, and not this script in question.